# What is the URL for installing SuiteCloud IDE on an Eclipse device?

Tags: installation, netsuite, suitecloud

When I try to install the SuiteCloud IDE on an Eclipse device, I'm getting this error:

[image: could not find URL error]

Apparently this URL is incorrect. What's the correct URL? Or is there another issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like they changed the link again, but the doc has not been updated.

The following link worked for me (notice the omission of "system.") :

http://netsuite.com/download/ide/update_18_2

For accounts with the 19.1 release, the following link works:

http://netsuite.com/download/suitecloud-sdk/ideplugin/eclipse/19.1

Answer (score 4):

It looks like they changed the URL, but not the documentation.  I have to use the following URLs.

1. http://system.netsuite.com/download/ide/update_16_2
2. http://system.netsuite.com/download/ide/update_17_1

Comment: If your NetSuite account is on version 16.2, use:
http://system.netsuite.com/download/ide/update_16_2
If your NetSuite account is on version 17.1, use:
http://system.netsuite.com/download/ide/update_17_1

Comment: Seems the URL changes every year.
Please try this (for 2018):
http://system.netsuite.com/download/ide/update_18_1

Answer (score 2):

URL changes ever year so correct URL is:
SuiteCloud IDE Site - https://system.netsuite.com/download/suitecloud-sdk/ideplugin/eclipse/21.1

Answer (score 1):

For compatibility reasons, your IDE plug-in version must match the version of your NetSuite account.

For accounts on version 20.1, use:
https://system.netsuite.com/download/suitecloud-sdk/ideplugin/eclipse/20.1

You can check Netsuite version at bottom of home page

Example: *Release 2020.1*

Answer (score 0):

Updated for 2022:

**If you want to get the latest changes automatically every time the plug-in is updated, use:**

https://system.netsuite.com/download/suitecloud-sdk/ideplugin/webstorm/latest/updatePlugins.xml

**If your account is on version 2022.1, use:**
https://system.netsuite.com/download/suitecloud-sdk/ideplugin/webstorm/22.1/updatePlugins.xml

This was pulled from the following documentation page on Oracle's site: https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_1529431804.html